# Get authentication token.id from OpenAm within Saml response

Tags: token, saml, openam

I have implemented SSO with paspport-saml and OpenAM. I can get certain user attributes such as id,givenName etc.
But now I want to get authentication token id with Saml response for further authentication of web services.

How I can get authentication token id with Saml response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get SAML assertion Id from saml response or you can use nameID based on ID provider setting it will contain either userName or principle object.

```
String ID = credential.getAuthenticationAssertion().getID();

or 

String userName = credential.getNameID().getValue();
```